# Custom Fields for Content Query Web Part for Pages Library

Tags: 2013, web-part, content-query-web-part

In SharePoint 2013, I have a Pages library full of press releases. A press release page layout contains the following: Title, Article Date, Contact Name, Contact E-mail Address, Page Content.

On the homepage, I want to display the 10 most recent press releases and only display Title, Article Date and Page Content.

The custom Content Query Web Part has Title and Description fields I can use for Title and Page Content. How do I add the field for Article Date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create/modify the `itemStyle` for your `CQWP` with your custom field like `AreticleDate`.

**Steps:**

- Open your Root site via SharePoint Designer.
- Go to all files > `Style library` > `XSL Style Sheets` > `ItemStyle.xml`
- Create a copy from `ItemStyle.xml` then > Edit it as advanced mode.

[image]

- Find the currently selected item style name > at any appropriate place in this template add

[image]

> ```
> <div class="article-date">
> <xsl:value-of select="@ArticleDate" />
> </div>
> ```

- Save > Check In > Publish as Major Version.
- After you finish > go to your QCWP > Edit it > and select your custom style from Presentation > Styles > Item Style.

[image]

- Bind the fields to display based on your fields in your page.

See also :- [Displaying Custom Fields in a SharePoint 2013 Content Query Web Part](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/displaying-custom-fields-sharepoint-2013-content-query-web-part/)

Comment: Can we add the Web Part Property with the Content Query Web Part, If yes Please provide me answer http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/197550/custom-property-for-the-content-query-web-part-sharepoint-2013

Comment: are you need to add a new field at fields to display section ? or new custom property ?

Comment: New Custom Property with content query.

Comment: #M.Qassas, Can you please let me know the path.

Comment: Dear @Ram, I am sorry for late reply , but really I didn't do this before for a content query web part,  I did it only for custom web part, and as you see in this thread it's related to displayed fields at item style, meanwhile , I am trying to find any solution since you communicate with me , once I got it I will inform you :) , Hope you get your solution ASAP :)