# Custom property for the Content Query Web Part SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-query-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part, item-styles

I have to create **Custom Property** with the Content Query Web Part.

I need this **Property** for the limit the number of rows to display and rotation time with CQWP.

How to add those properties in the **Itemstyle.xslt & ContentQueryMain.xslt**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can limit the returned rows already in the wp's properties.

Comment: OK, What about the rotation speed or any other text like Web Part Description.
My simple Question is - How can I create the custom property?