# Set the default value to field/property with the Content Query Web Part 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, content-query-web-part, item-styles

I have to set the **default value** to the web part **field/Property**.

This is same as **custom web part**, we can set the default value to the property. Same I have to implement in the Content Query Web Part.

Is it possible & how?

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure the Content Query web part with default value in a page
2. Export the web part. (You can open up the exported web part using a
   text editor and see the default values)
3. Import the web part to the  Web Part Gallery with a DIFFERENT NAME (Don't replace existing CQWP)

Then, web part is ready to be imported to pages with default values you defined.

Comment: How can I add the CQWP property like custom property?
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/197550/custom-property-for-the-content-query-web-part-sharepoint-2013