# cqwp: formatting a date inside a standard template

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, xslt, date-time

I do not have a formal knowledge of XSLT so my successes are with attempts.

I would like to know one information once for all. Sometimes I need a slight modification on the templates such as the 'title and description' (internal name 'no image') with a date field in place of the description.

I get date and time while I just want to have the date.

I have written this in a copy of the template (only the portion relevant to the date, the rest is ok.

```
            <div class="Description">
          <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@Date, 2057, 3)" />
        </div>
```

and I get that the CQWP is broken.

1. do I have to keep the class description? (line 1)
2. is the ddwrt correct? what do I have to write after @? (line 2) My Date in the source list is called 'Action delivery date'

I have also copied on top

```
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: `@Date` should be `@InternalNameOfYourDateTimeField`

Comment: So my @ should be @Action%5Fx0020%5Fdelivery%5Fx0020%5Fdate ???

Comment: It should be `@Action_x0020_delivery_x0020_date` as in @M.Qassas answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**do I have to keep the class description?**

this does not affect the value of  `XSL`, it's a `div tag` that use `description` class for only design/display purpose

**is the ddwrt correct?**

yes it's correct , **2057** denote to `LCID` that is English for united kingdom , and 3 is `format flag` that display date as this format `23 March 2016`

Also, you can replace it with **1033** for English-United State .

[image]

**what do I have to write after @? (line 2) My Date in the source list is called 'Action delivery date'**

You should get the internal name of `'Action delivery date'` and but it after `@`

so space should be replaced by `_x0020_` so the internal name should look like

```
Action_x0020_delivery_x0020_date
```

And the final ddwrt

```
  <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(@Action_x0020_delivery_x0020_date, 2057, 3)" />
```

**Note :** to get the internal name > open your list > list settings > click on your column > from the address bar check the field query string  `Field=`

**Note :** you can add it as `@Actiondeliverydate` where this is the field display name but when you try to edit CQWP and set it's value you should add its internal name.

**[Update]**

Although the above instructions are valid , but unfortunately, Susan told me : It does not display anything.

In fact, The date variable is shown but the `forecolor` is white , so you will tell me I should remove `description class` ?

But this also not a solution, if you remove the class it still shows as white so you should set your custom style at the div tag like this `<div style="color:black">` or build your custom class

So the final code based on the provided template in chat, should be

```
<xsl:template name="Actions" match="Row[@Style='Actions']" mode="itemstyle">
    <xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
            <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <div class="item link-item">
        <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.CallPresenceStatusIconTemplate"/>
        <a href="{$SafeLinkUrl}" title="{@LinkToolTip}">
          <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams = 'True'">
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
              <xsl:value-of select="@OnClickForWebRendering"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="$ItemsHaveStreams != 'True' and @OpenInNewWindow = 'True'">
            <xsl:attribute name="onclick">
              <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="$OnClickTargetAttribute"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle"/>
        </a>
        <div style="color:black">
          <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Actiondeliverydate), 2057, 3)" />
        </div>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

**[Output]**

[image]

**Note:**

In the above example : I used `@Actiondeliverydate` not the internal name, I found out this the field display name and not should be the internal name ,

but when you edit your CQWP web part , you should provide the internal name  of `'Action delivery date'` field that in this case is `Action_x0020_delivery_x0020_date` that will be transferred back to `Action delivery date`

[image]

Comment: It does not display anything. See updated topic. This is what I see inside the CQ, and the result is that only the title is displayed, not the date.

Comment: Hi @susan it looks like you tried to modify an item style ?, should you update your question  with full modified code for only this  item style , also should you tell me from where you h=got this screenshot ? is it when you edit your CQWP ?

Comment: I made a copy of the style called NOIMAGE and just modified description. The screenshot is from my computer, this is what I see

Comment: I know susan it's from your computer :) , I am wondering is it show when you edit your CQWP at field to display section as i have mentioned at this answer http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191972/custom-fields-for-content-query-web-part-for-pages-library/192033#comment209407_192033

Comment: yes, it is when I compile the CQWP

Comment: does it matter that the original date is field date with no time?

Comment: I think it will not affect,  based on the format flag 3 and LICD 2057 it will show the date without time as 23 March 2016,  by the way should you try this as the following : <xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDate(string(@Action_x0020_delivery_x0020_date), 2057, 3) "/>

Comment: even after adding string, it is still not showing anything, I have updated my image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48171/discussion-between-m-qassas-and-susan).

Comment: Hi, everything worked, just one thing I do not understand. In my original code the second line was starting with this <div class="Description">, then you told me to change it to "articledate", then in your final code, this has disappeared. Is it wrong to leave description or it is redundant?

Comment: Hi @susan As I told you it does not effect it's a defined class for description field so you can set your custom style as you want and as i did in my update , so no need to leave it !